# What happened to console in Chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

As part of another question I wrote

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/7PAEX/)

```
$(function () {
console.log("what"); alert("what")
    $("#list li").on("click",function() {
      $("#select-resultSpan").empty()
      console.log($(this).text());alert($(this).text())
      $("#select-resultSpan").append($(this).text());
   })
 });
```

but I see nothing in the console of Chrome 25.0.1364.172 for OSX 10.8.3

What happened?

Comment: Works for me.   Is your console set to show the **All** view or did you use one of the other views that is not showing console.log() messages?

Comment: Not that I know. I'll take a look